# Function to pull numbers from free text field and replace 'k' with '000'

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have a free text column in my data that contains both words and numbers. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

For example: "Johnny received 1,000 products."

I want to extract just the numbers from this column which I have successfully been able to do with the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNumericValue (@inputString varchar(500))
RETURNS varchar(500)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @integerPart INT
    SET @integerPart = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @inputString)

    BEGIN 
        WHILE @integerPart > 0
        BEGIN 
            SET @inputString = STUFF(@inputString, @integerPart, 1, '')
            SET @integerPart = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @inputString)
        END
    END 

    RETURN ISNULL(@inputString, 0)
END
GO
```

But there are a few observations that use units, ex: "Johnny received 1k products." Is there a way to modify this function so that when there is a number that has a "k" attached to it, it will replace the k with "000" or if there is a number that has a "m" attached to it, it will replace the m with "000000"?

There are also a few observations that include dates at the end of the sentence that should be excluded - only the first number found should be included.

Comment: A bit ugly but something like this perhaps: https://dbfiddle.uk/DC4_Opwu

Comment: @siggemannen this works great!! looks like there's a few rows that have dates in them as well that I didn't notice before and the function pulls the date in as well - "Johnny received 2k products on 8.26.2020" becomes 20008262020. Is it possible to only look at the first number so dates can be excluded?

Comment: Yes, but you need to rewrite the whole function. Right now you're doing an analogy of removing one piece of hay at a time to look for one needle. You should instead try to find a number looking string and parse it out once

Comment: This sounds like the problem is whatever is inserting the data and the design. These should all be inserted into different columns. The fact that you have a scenario you only highlight in the comments doesn't make this easier either. I suspect that if you "must" do this (rather than fixing your design) then T-SQL is not your friend.

Comment: @ThomA Unfortunately I have no control over how the data is inserted and it is not able to be changed

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following function which makes use of the built-in *translate* function to strip away non-numeric characters and then apply your "k" or "m" multipliers using some patindex checking combined with some case expression logic:

```
create or alter function dbo.getNumericValue (@inputString Varchar(500))
returns Varchar(20)
as 
begin
  return (
    select Try_Convert(Int, Replace(Translate(s,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,',Replicate('*',28)), '*','') 
      * Choose(case c when 'k' then 2 when 'm' then 3 else 1 end, 1, 1000, 1000000))
    from (select @inputString s)s
    cross apply(values( NullIf(PatIndex('%[0-9][mk] %', s), 0)))p(p)
    cross apply(values(Substring(s, p + 1, 1)))c(c)
  );
end;
```

Depending on your source data you can add any additional required punctuation to the list.

If running against a large set of rows I would use a table-valued function instead of scalar.

See a [demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QtQvE7lJ)